# Issue sending routed POST params

Tags: php, jquery, forms, http, post

I have problems with a submit form (or with the routing design) that deletes N table based on id.
I've a made a simple routing function that use the index php file:

```
function relativeRouter ($controller,$action,$query_data=""){
    $param = is_array($query_data) ? http_build_query($query_data) : "$query_data";
    $url = "index.php?controller=$controller&action=$action&$param";
    return $url;
```

The index create instances of controllers using controller=?&action=?.
It also bind the POST/GET params to the methods arguments (in an array, $params). (**im already aware to not use directly calls to superglobals**)

```
$params=array();
if(isset($_GET['controller'])&&isset($_GET['action'])){
    $c = $_GET['controller'];   
    $a = $_GET['action'];    
    // add all query string additional params to method signature i.e. &id=x&category=y
    $queryParams = array_keys($_GET);
    $queryValues = array_values($_GET);
        for ($i=2;$i<count($queryParams);$i++) {
            $params[$queryParams[$i]] = $queryValues[$i];   
        }

if ($_POST) {
print_r($_POST); // THIS CONTAINS ONLY 1 PASSED ID.
// add all query string additional params to method signature i.e. &id=x&category=y
$queryParams = array_keys($_POST);
$queryValues = array_values($_POST);
        for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST);$i++) {
            $params[$queryParams[$i]] = $queryValues[$i];   
        }
        }
include_once APP_ROOT."/controller/$c.php";
$controller = new $c();//CombustibiliController
$controller->$a($params);//inserimento

}  else {   
//attiva controller predefinito    
$controller = new Admin();
$controller->index();
}
```

The routing works well in a form with different HTML form item names. (name='') but i'm expriencing problems by passing an array of id that are used for a multi-checkbox delete.

The $_POST is arriving with an array with only one items instead of many :

```
Array ( [ids] => 110 )
```

While works with no hassle with the insert form:

```
Array ( [title] => 435 [desc] => 5534 )
```

Here the table view:

```
   <?php
if (isset($products)) {
$action = relativeRouter("ProductsController", "deleteProducts");
$html="<form id='multiselect' action='$action' method='POST'>\n";
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $html.= "<tr>\n"
            ."<td><input type='checkbox' name='ids' value='".$product->id."'></td>\n"
            ."<td>".$product->id."</td>\n"
            ."<td>".$product->title."</td>\n"
            ."<td>".$product->description."</td>\n"
            ."<td>".$product->image."</td>\n"
            ."</tr>\n";
}
$html.="</form>\n";
echo $html;
} 
?>
```

And here the jQuery that runs the form from a button:

```
 <script>
       function send() {
           $('#multiselect').submit();
           $('.play-confirm-modal').modal('hide');
       }

$('.play-crud-delete').on('click',function(){

    var checked = $( "input:checkbox:checked" ).length;
    if(checked>0) {
       $('.play-confirm-modal').modal('show');
       console.log(checked);
    } else {
        alert("No selected checkboxes");
    }
});




</script>
```

Hope someone can help. Firefox networks show module params but the POST only contains one of them, always the last.

Comment: `<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' value='".$product->id."'>` replace this and check. `name` should contain array operator for multivalue

Comment: it works. it's something related to php? i have never done something like that with Java and Groovy.

Comment: Yes in php multidimensional always with array operator

Comment: Thank you so much i wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Added as answer so in future if any one like to know they can see answer instead of a comment. If it is solved please accept it to avoid redundant answer in SO

Comment: You reply is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' value='".$product->id."'>`

replace this and check. name should contain `array operator` for `multivalue`